# Is Struts 1x compatible with java 1.7

Tags: java, struts-1

Now I need to upgrade my project from java 1.3 to 1.7

Is there any issue facing application with this upgrade?

Comment: upgrade struts also....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No problems for jdk7, but jdk8 faces problems in the natural sort order of `<options>`-tag and a few other problems.

Why do i answer? JDK7 is [EoPU](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html), you shall not use it anymore.

Comment: Do you have any reference documentation listing the known issues when using jdk8

Comment: In struts1? No. The interrest would be too small for official documentation. You can read the sourcecode, look for usages of iterations over unsorted collections where the first match is taken without the case that a different order may have a value jdk7 would use. The order of unsorted collections has changed between jdk7 and jdk8 and the developers did often not take care about different random-sortings